# How to parametrically represent an ARBITRARY circle in polar coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, polar-coordinates

So, we know that any circle centered at the origin $(0,0)$ can be written in polar coordinates as:

$r=f(\theta)=C \iff \langle\theta(t), r(t)\rangle=\langle t,C\rangle$

Where $C\in \mathbb{R}$ is the radius of the circle.

However, let's say I move my circle to any point in the polar plane, if this was cartesian coordinates, one can simpy state that the original circle was parametrized as:

$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle C\cos(t),C\sin(t)\rangle$

So shifting it is simply adding an offset vector, giving us:

$\langle x,y\rangle=\langle C\cos(t)+v_x, C\sin(t)+v_y\rangle$

Is it correct to say that the parametric function:

$\langle \theta,r\rangle=\langle t+v_\theta,C+v_r\rangle$ is moving the circle $v_\theta$ radians in the counter-clockwise direction and $v_r$ length units away from the origin?

Comment: Adding an offset to $\theta$ and to $r$ is not the same as adding an offset to $x$ and $y$. That parametrization will just give you a circle with radius $C+v_r$. The offset on $\theta$ just means that you'll trace it out with a different starting/ending point.

Comment: You might be looking for the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805945/parametric-polar-equation-of-a-circle?rq=1

Comment: You might also find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Circle